# Remove hanging from bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I currently am developing my template for my thesis. The bibliography style should be the `aiaa` style. I have done this by using the `new.aiaa.bst` provided by the AIAA on overleaf. I am also using the package `natbib`. While the style is okay, the format isn't what I need.

[image: The bibliography]

I want the first line to have an indent and the others to have none. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indent is controlled by `\bibhang` :

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}

\begin{document}


test
\cite{knuth}

\bibliographystyle{new-aiaa}

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the 2n-nth row.

Is there a possibility to add an indent to the first row?